# XSL for each not working

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have an XSL variable `qwe` which holds an xml like this

```
 <Column1>
  <TT TXT1="Skriveartikler" />
  <TT TXT1="Kridt" />
  <TT TXT1="Tavlekridt" />
</Column1>
```

And my for loop is like this

```
         <xsl:for-each select="$qwe/Column1/TT">
            <textarea>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </textarea>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

But code execution never happens inside loop.Means no texarea is printed.
can any one give any reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

will give you the string value of the `TT` element, which is the empty string in your example.  If you want to display the `Skriveartikler` etc. text then you need

```
<xsl:value-of select="@TXT1" />
```

If you're not getting the `<textarea>` elements at all then presumably your variable doesn't contain what you expect.  Is the `Column1` XML you give in the question a fragment selected from a larger document that has a default namespace declaration (`xmlns="..."`)?  If so you'll need to bind the namespace to a prefix in your stylesheet and use that prefix in the XPaths.

Another possibility is that in XSLT 1.0 if you declare a variable like

```
<xsl:variable name="qwe">
  <Column1>
    <TT TXT1="Skriveartikler" />
    <TT TXT1="Kridt" />
    <TT TXT1="Tavlekridt" />
  </Column1>
</xsl:variable>
```

then the variable will contain a *result tree fragment*, not a node set, and the only thing you can do with a RTF is copy it to the output tree - you can't navigate into it using XPath expressions.  If you want to do this, you'll need to convert the RTF to a node set using an extension function such as [`exslt:node-set()`](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But my problem is that for loop never executes.Means even the blank textarea is not printing.

Comment: @AthulKSurendran I've added another couple of possible explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The variable doesn't contain what you are telling us it contains. We can't tell why without seeing how you set up the variable.